# Crear cadena de caracteres sin ningún repetido

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy creando una aplicación que me genera contraseñas aleatorias. Para generar contraseñas de una longitud n no tengo ningún problema, pero estoy intentando añadir una opción para que las contraseñas generadas tengan caracteres únicos. Tengo el siguiente código:

```kotlin
if (activityMainCheckRemoveChars.isChecked.isTrue()) {
                        val charsForRemove = activityMainInputRemoveChars.text.toString().toList()
                        val charsList = ('A'..'Z').toMutableList()
                        charsList.removeAll(charsForRemove)
                        val char = charsList.filter { !it.isWhitespace() }.random().toString()
                        uniqueCharacters.add(char)
                        password += char

                    } else {
                        val char = ('A'..'Z').random().toString()
                        uniqueCharacters.add(char)
                    }
```

La lista llamada `uniqueCharacters` ha sido uno de mis intentos de hacer esta tarea, donde intentaba crear una lista auxiliar que fuera añadiendo todos los caracteres y después comparar dicha lista con la contraseña que se estaba formando, pero ahí me he quedado ya que quiero que si algún caracter está repetido, reemplace dicho caracter por uno que no esté repetido.

También he pensado en utilizar un `HashSet`, pero creo que tendría el problema de que si quiero generar una password de por ejemplo 8 caracteres y el `HashSet` encuentra que 3 son iguales, al final obtendría una cadena de 5 caracteres, y no es lo que pretendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que a mi se me ocurre es que, antes de añadir una letra a la contraseña, la asignes a una variable y verifiques a través del uso del método `contains()` si esa letra ya está en la contraseña. Esto puede servir de condición de un `while()`. En este caso si contains() devuelve false, el `while` terminará y la letra se asignará a la contraseña. En caso de que `contains()` de `true`, porque la letra ya existe en la contraseña, volverá a dar otra aleatoria que se asignará a la primera variable con la letra nueva. Entonces el `while()` comprobará de nuevo si la contiene hasta que el resultado sea `false` y entonces la asigne. Yo añadiría un fragmento de código tal como este:

```
val char = ('A'..'Z').random().toString()
while(array.contains(char)){
    char = ('A'..'Z').random().toString()
}
uniqueCharacters.add(char)
```

Comment: Te marco la tuya como respuesta ya que es la que al final me ha servdo, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un rango de la *'a'* a la *'z'* (`'a'..'z'`). Luego barajas los elementos y por último sacas los primeros n elementos. Así no tienes que verificar si hay elementos repetidos y lo haces todo con 1 línea de código:

```
val letters = ('a'..'z').shuffled().take(n).toCharArray()
```

Solo cambias la `n` por la longitud que necesitas y el resultado será un `CharArray` de la longitud que pusiste.

Comment: ¿Pero no puede caber la posibilidad de que una de las veces que baraje dicha cadena, coincida el caracter?

Comment: @Ludiras Partes de un rango de la 'a' a la 'z'. Es como un mazo de cartas y simplemente lo barajas y sacas las primeras n cartas. El único problema que podrías tener es el de intentar sacar más elementos de los que existen en el "mazo", aunque el resultado que obtendrías sería la totalidad de los elementos existentes.

Comment: Hasta ahi de acuerdo, pero a no ser que cada vez que se saca un elemento, este elemento se elimine y no pueda volver a ser sacado, existe la minima posibilidad de que al barajar dicho mazo, el azar decida que dos o más veces esté el numero x en la misma posición n. Si se van extrayendo los números y son eliminados del rango principal entonces no he dicho nada, dime si es así.

Comment: @Ludiras El rango no tiene elementos repetidos. Luego los barajas y tendrás los mismos elementos iniciales pero en orden aleatorio y a partir de ahí sacas los primeros n elementos. Haz la prueba y saca todos los elementos o más de los que existen. Verás que saldrán todos los elementos iniciales en orden aleatorio, aunque le hayas pedido más elementos solamente saldrá la cantidad que contiene el rango. En realidad nunca estás eliminando ni insertando nada dentro del rango, solo lo estás recorriendo de inicio a fin, por eso nunca se repetirá ninguno.